# Stored procedure doesn`t return OUT parameter

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I have problem with using stored procedures to create item in the MSSQL 2008 Database.
I`m using Flex on client side with ADEP for server connection.

Database procedure is quite simple:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testInsert_procedure]
    @id INT OUT,
    @v1 VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @v2 VARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO test1 (v1, v2)
    VALUES (@v1, @v2)

    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    SELECT @id as id;
END
GO
```

This is the destination from config file for this stored procedure:

```
<destination id="TestTableInsert">
    <adapter ref="java-dao" />
    <properties>
      <source>flex.data.assemblers.SQLAssembler</source>
      <scope>application</scope>
      <metadata>
        <identity property="id"/>
      </metadata>
      <server>
        <database>
          <datasource>java:comp/env/jdbc/TEST</datasource>
        </database>
        <actionscript-class>classes.TestClass</actionscript-class>
        <create-item>
          <procedure name="testInsert_procedure">
            <procedure-param property-value="#id#" type="OUT" />
            <procedure-param property-value="#v1#" />
            <procedure-param property-value="#v2#" />
          </procedure>
        </create-item>
      </server>
    </properties>
  </destination>
```

Using of this configuration gives next error:

```
Jun 25, 2013 2:47:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: [Data Services] [DEBUG] SQL Assembler jdbc exception on operation=create-item error=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 1.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
```

I`have found that is might be JDBC bug...
So, it just wrong configuration to get OUTPUT parameters or this is really JDBC bug?

**Update**: Java is using on the server side with Microsoft JDBC driver 4.0

Comment: I removed the Flex tag as this has nothing to do w/ Flex.  What is your server side language?  Java?  Or ColdFusion?  Or something different?

Comment: Thanks for response.Server side is Java.